# Pygame, blitting text character by character, and centering it

Tags: python, pygame

I have this to center normal text

```
text = textfont.render(text, True, WHITE)
tpos = ((winwidth/2) - text.get_rect().width, (winheight/2) - text.get_rect().height)
```

But if I want to blit letter by letter, AND center it, my math skills are failing me, and I dont know how. I have tried the following:

```
    for x in range(len(title)):             #if blit letter by letter
        twid = (winwidth - (2*tpos[0])) / len(title)
        win.blit(textfont.render(title[x], False, WHITE), (tpos[0] + (((x+1) * 20) + twid), tpos[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to measure/calculate the resulting width of the text before drawing it, then you can center it. I suggest drawing text on an image and center the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `screen.get_rect()` to get a rect with the size of the screen. If the text gets changed, rerender the text surface and get a new rect from it. Set the center of the new rect to the center of the screen_rect and then just blit the text_surface at the text_rect. (Type something to make the text string longer.)

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 46)
    color = pg.Color('sienna1')

    text = 'text'
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                text += event.unicode
                text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
                text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

        screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
        screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```